# group and find max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I must find availability of some it servers, and a must group them and find the max.
(for example billings have 2 db servers,3 application servers. they are in cluster.)
so i must calculate the availability for each of them(db servers,application servers)
by combining if one db server is up one is down service is up. how can i group them and find the max value for each of them?
here is my query,which have shows availability of all IP. how can i group by service,application servers... i wont to show all information in one table(availability of service in one column,of application server in one column,of IP in one column)

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT Resultdate, 
       [SERVICE]  ,
       [SERVICE TYPE] ,
       [IP] , 
       ailyAvailability
  FROM [Orion].[dbo].[DepartmentNodesNew] AS t1

left join 
       (select round(1-(sum([DownTimeMin])/(1440*count(*))),4)*100  as DailyAvailability,
              count(*) as Node,
              ResultDate  ,
              [Departament]  ,
              [IPAdress]
   from  [Orion].[dbo].[OrionEventsNodeDownTime] 
   group by  [Departament] ,[IPAdress] , ResultDate) AS t2
   on t1.IP=t2.IPAdress 

   where t2.DailyAvailability is not null 

    and cast(ResultDate as date) = '2014-12-09'

            group by Resultdate, [SERVICE]  ,[SERVICE TYPE] ,[IP]   , DailyAvailability
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Resultdate /SERVICE /SERVICEavailability/ SERVICE TYPE/ SERVICETYPEavailability/ IP/ ipavailability/ DailyAvailability  this are columns i wont to see